# Keep track of the result of accumulation for operation without inverse

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, tree

I have an operation `A * A -> A`, which is commutative and associative. This means the order I apply it in doesn't matter, as long as I use the same elements. Nice.

I have to apply it to a list of values. To be more precise, I have to use it as the operation to accumulate the values of the list. So far, so good.

I then have a series of requests to add an element to the list, or erase it from the list. After each insertion or deletion, I have to return the new accumulated value for the new list. Simple, right?

The problem is I don't have an inverse; that is no operation '`/`' able to remove `b` if I only know `a * b` and tell me the other operand must have been `a`. (in fact, there isn't even an identity element)

So, my only obvious option is to accumulate again at every deletion -in linear time.

Can I do better? I've thought a lot about it.

And the answer is, of course I can... if I really want: I need to implement a custom binary tree, maybe a red/black one to have good worst case guarantees. Have next to the `value` an additional `cache` storing the result of the whole subtree.

```
cache = value * left.cache * right.cache
```

Maintain this invariant after every operation; then the root cache is the result.

However, "implement a custom R/B tree while maintaining an additional invariant" isn't something I'm particularly comfortable at doing. Well I would do it, but not swear by its correctness. Plus, the constant before the log would probably be significant. It seems pretty unwieldy, to do a simple thing like keeping track of an accumulation.

Does anyone see a better solution?

For completeness: the operation is a union of filters. A filter is a couple `(code, mask)`, and a value "passes the filter" if (C bitwise operators) `(value ^ code) & mask == 0`; that is, if its bit corresponding to bits set in `mask` are equal to the corresponding bits in `code`. The union therefore sets to 0 (ignored) the bits where masks or codes differ, and keeps the ones which are the same.

Bonus appreciation to anyone finding a way to exploit the specific properties of the operation to get a solution more efficient than it is possible for the general problem I abstracted! ;-)

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: The list which you mentioned in your question is made of what? values or codes or masks?, please be specific.

Comment: the operation acts on filters, which are couples of code and mask. For instance `struct { unsigned int code; unsigned int mask; };`. It can be implemented as `res.code = lhs.code; res.mask = lhs.mask & rhs.mask & ~(lhs.code ^ rhs.code);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem you could keep track for each bit x:

1. The total number of times that bit x is set to 1 in a mask
2. The total number of times that bit x is set to 1 in a mask and bit x of code is equal to 0
3. The total number of times that bit x is set to 1 in a mask and bit x of code is equal to 1

With these 3 counts (for each bit) it is straightforward to compute the union of all the filters.

The complexity is O(R) (where R is the number of bits in mask) to add or remove a filter.

Comment: ...well, you are completely right! (actually it seems I need only two of those counts, isn't the first a sum of the other two? And the count for 0 is the complement to n) Truly, I was so taken in with bitwise operation that I just couldn't think of counting past 1... thanks! :)